# ParseError.tagTemplateNotFound("short\").val")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vapor, leaf

I am working on a very simple Vapor app. I am currently working on one of the views:

```
#extend("base")

#export("body") {
    <form>
        <div class="row">
                <div class="six columns">
                    <label for="exampleEmailInput">Acronym</label>
                    <input class="u-full-width" type="email" id="short">
                    </div>
                <div class="six columns">
                    <label for="exampleRecipientInput">Long form</label>
                    <input class="u-full-width" type="email" id="long">
                </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="five columns"></div>
            <div class="two columns">
                <a class="button button-primary" id="submit" href="/acronym/all">Save Acronym</a>
            </div>
        <div class="five columns"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function setHref() {
            var short = $("#short").val();
        }
    </script>
}
```

This code works until I add the `short` variable to the `setHref` function. Then I get a parsing error:

```
Uncaught Error: ParseError.tagTemplateNotFound("short\").val"). Use middleware to catch this error and provide a better response. Otherwise, a 500 error page will be returned in the production environment.
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leaf is finding `#short` and parsing it as a tag. My guess is you're looking for some type of escaping mechanism. Here's some options:

```
#()short => #short
#raw() { #short } => #short
```

Comment: Hi @Logan, I am having hard time getting this working with Leaf 3.0.0, could you point me the right direction?

Comment: I found out that you have to register a tag for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44524372/swift-vapor-leaf-deliver-html-in-a-variable