# Swift Vapor Leaf deliver html in a variable

Tags: html, swift, vapor, leaf

I need to create a complex html-table inside a Swift Vapor App.

Problem is: Leaf doesn't seem to support counting up variables like #(somevar += 1) nor concatenating string variables like #(somevar1 + somevar2)

So I decided to create my complex table inside the App and transfer it to the html template inside a variable. (in php I'm used to doing this all the time)

In the template I'd call the variable like

```
#(table)
```

but turns out, I'm getting the plain html code as leaf escapes all variables.

But there is the #raw() function to print out plain html as such.

So I do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head><title>Server</title></head>
<body>
<..>

<form action="parameters" method="post">

// here is the thing: leaf gets a html table within the string 'table'.
// If I do it like that lead doesn't recognize #(table) as a leaf variable.
#raw( #(table) )

<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

only to find out that #raw() does not look for variables but just prints out unescaped what is between the {}. So I still get in the website "#(table)" instead of my complex html-table.

So now I'm stuck. How do I get App-generated html code into the template as html?

Probably I am doing this all wrong. How do I get html code inside a leaf template at all? Or do I have to send the whole page then myself, as a http stream with a header…?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: edited it trying to point out my question more clearly…

Answer (score 6):

**Update**

Since Vapor 3 the `#raw(<var>)` tag was not embedded by default in `--template=web` when creating your Vapor Leaf project. I had to register it manually in my `configure.swift` file :

```
/// Leaf add tags
services.register { container -> LeafTagConfig in
    var config = LeafTagConfig.default()
    config.use(Raw(), as: "raw")   // #raw(<myVar>) to print it as raw html in leaf vars
    return config
}
```

*https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/leaf/custom-tags/*

Also if someone is seeking for the complete list of available tags, you can silmply search for `TagRenderer` in vapor dependencies, which is the protocol to conform if you want to create a custom tag :

[image: Available Tags]

Hope this can help

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are not taking in user input to create this table, you should be able to use this:

```
#raw(table)
```

This does the same thing as `#(table)`, but it doesn't escape the HTML, so it will properly render. Just make sure you are not making yourself vulnerable to XSS attacks if you do this.

Comment: I found I has to use #raw(table) without the {}.  If I included the {} the result was blank (Leaf 2.0.1).

Answer (score 1):

In vapor 4 it is:

#unsafeHTML(variable)